# Importing Projects into Eclipse + Python

Tags: eclipse, python-2.7, pydev

How to import an Python project not created through Eclipse into Eclipse.

Using Eclipse Luna

-Shiva S

Answer (score 2):

Follow these following steps...

- First add **pydev interpreter** in eclipse [Follow this link](http://pydev.org/manual_101_interpreter.html)
- Configure the pydev interpreter
  **windows->preferences->Pydev->Interpreter-Python**
- Then import the project **File->import->General->Existing project into
  workspace**

Comment: Import Existing Project into workspace will work once if the project to be imported is created by eclipse. In my case it is not created by eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

The basic solution is creating a new project (just set the location of the new project to the existing sources).

The FAQ covers that: http://pydev.org/faq.html#PyDevFAQ-HowdoIimportexistingprojects%2FsourcesintoPyDev%3F if you have something more complex you want to do.